# Redis reJson: JSON.ARRAYAPPEND returns WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: arrays, object, redis, append, command-line-interface

On redis-rejson I'm trying to compute an arrayappend. 
I put in an object, a path, a json, and a array as indicated in the [documentation](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonarrappend) .

**Brief:**

My objective => I want to create an array of object with Redis

My aim => that array of object allow me to put an user session in my redis cache

My desirated output => `" [{objectOne}, {objectTwoJustAdded}]"`

My problem => seems I put the wrong type in the console.

Here my   command:

```
   JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "." '{"user1":"1"}' [... CartModel]
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

But as you can see it doesn't works, I have tried some variations:

```
    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "." '{"user1":"1"}'
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "here a vlue"
    ERR wrong number of arguments for 'JSON.ARRAPPEND' command

    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "." 'here a value'
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "." '["here a value"]'
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.arrappend test36 "."  [ 'example', '.', '{"firstname":"Jon","lastname":"Doe"}' ] 
    Invalid argument(s)
    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.get CartModel
    {"userID":{"beverage":{},"sandwich":{},"treat":{},"dessert":{}}}
    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND test36 "." '{"user1":"1"}' [... CartModel]
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

    127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.ARRAPPEND arr . 0
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

neither works.
So how do that?
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an array first in the database then use it as a recipient for the other Json objects:

```
127.0.0.1:6380> JSON.set objectArray "." "[]"
OK
127.0.0.1:6380> json.arrappend objectArray "." '{"appenda":"a value"}'
1
127.0.0.1:6380> json.get objectArray
[{"appenda":"a value"}]
```

PS: Why the programmers like to make vague documentations? it's like an appealing meal which refuses to be eaten.